# Unable to detect user pressing 'Cancel' from window.prompt()

Tags: javascript

According to what I've researched, the function should be able to detect whether input is empty or not as well as if 'Cancel' is pressed. However, only the first two things work and whenever I click on 'Cancel', nothing happens.

I've posted the whole function code, but my issue is with the `if-else` statement. I've tested this on IE7, Chrome and Firefox.

JavaScript:

```
function countStrings()
{
    var sequence = [];
    sequence = window.prompt( "Enter a sequence of values", "a 1 b 2" ).split( " " );
    if ( sequence[ 0 ] === "" )
    {
        // user pressed OK or Return; input is empty
    }
    else if ( sequence )
    {
        // user pressed OK or Return; input not empty.
    }
    else
    {
        // User pressed Cancel; not being detected/not working.
        // Nothing happens.
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
    <script type = "text/javaScript" src="./practice.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="beach_ready">
    <h1>Practising JavaScript functions</h1>
    <p>
        <input id="f" type="button" value="Function" onclick="countStrings();" />
        Click to the count number of strings in an array
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sequence=window.prompt();

if (sequence===""){
//then I entered nothing and pressed OK
} else
if (sequence===null){
//then I pressed cancel.
} else {
//then I entered something good. process it
//..rest of your code...
}
```

To answer your question:
`null.split(" ");` results in an error, because you can't call any methods on `null`, because its `null` and isn't an object and doesn't have methods to call.

So when this line happens

```
sequence = window.prompt( "Enter a sequence of values", "a 1 b 2" ).split( " " );
```

and the user presses cancel, this evaluates to `sequence = null.split(" ")` and your script bombs out. So you need to get the value first, see what it is, then don't call split on it until you have determined it's safe to do so. Like this:

```
var sequence, sequenceInput;
    sequenceInput = window.prompt( "Enter a sequence of values", "a 1 b 2" );
    if ( sequenceInput=== "" )
    {
        // user pressed OK or Return; input is empty
    }
    else if ( sequenceInput===null )
    {
        // user pressed cancel
    }
    else
    {
        //user entered something
        sequence=sequenceInput.split(" ");
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working either. Wouldn't my `else` statement go there in case I pressed `Cancel` anyway?

Comment: Your question was "how do I detect if the user pressed cancel" and then you posted the code for your entire application. Please reduce it to a simple test case demonstrating the problem you are having. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright, have a look at the question now. I just posted everything so that someone could just copy paste it and run it if they needed to.

Comment: Thanks! I get what your saying about posting all the code so someone could run it, but here the minimum is the preferred, since *even that* could still be run by a user, and it also means that someone has an easier time diagnosing the issue without having to take the time to run the application themselves.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on Notepad++ so it's hard to see errors like that. I'm probably making things way harder on myself than they should be.

Comment: actually, notepad++ isn't too bad for javascript, you wouldn't be able to see that error in a proper IDE either since it doesn't surface until the code is evaluated. however, if you are using Chrome or FF you should be able to see the error in your browser's console. Open the console by hitting F12, then reload the page, and you should see errors printed there

Comment: my other note would be that it is never a good idea to call a method on the return value of a function that may return null. Since `window.prompt()` has the possibility of returning null, in general you always want to test the value before calling any methods on it

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very helpful to know. I started with JavaScript today.